# how to mock an es6 constructor with jest

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, mocking, jestjs

after reading loads of jest docs, i have been unable to get a simple setup to work. i have a very simple example, that throws the error:

```
expect(received).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(expected)
Matcher error: received value must be a mock or spy function
Received has type:  function
Received has value: [Function Foo]
```

the jest docs say "Calling jest.mock('./sound-player') returns a useful "automatic mock" you can use to spy on calls to the class constructor and all of its methods. It replaces the ES6 class with a mock constructor, and replaces all of its methods with mock functions that always return undefined.

based on that info, im not sure why the following code is not working. i am looking for the simplest implementation to build from, so i can continue learning from. if anyone can explain why it doesn't work, and point me in the direction of a solution... :)

foo.js

```js
export default class Foo {
  constructor() {
    console.log('CONSTRUCTOR')
    return 'foo'
  }
}
```

foo.test.js

```js
import Foo from '@org/foo'
jest.mock('@org/foo')

it('should ...', function() {
  new Foo();
  expect(Foo).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1)
});
```

Comment: It's working for me. Need more info.